# Open ViewController right after viewDidLoad without .xib file

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, storyboard, viewcontroller

I'm working with Storyboards so as far as I know I have not xib files. What I want to do is: when the app launches, I want to check if anything has been written to the db in the past and, if not, open a view, which is not the standard view. (Because if the db is not empty, a other view should be opened as it is standard view.)

What I've tried so far: (in viewDidLoad / viewDidAppear)

```
ViewController *vs = [Viewcontroller new];
[self presentViewController:vs animated:YES completion:nil];
```

This leads to a black screen. Nothings happens, it just stays black.
Next I tried to perform a segue but this results in a view opening itself again and again.

Is there a common / standard way to do this?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, you can instantiate a UIViewController instance from a Storyboard instance:

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"YourStoryboard" bundle:nil];
UIViewController *newController = [storyboard instantiateInitialViewController];
```

This assumes that you are going to start from the initial view controller within that StoryBoard instance.

You could pair this with your conditional to perform the following:

```
UIViewController *newViewController = nil;
if([self databaseHasNewInformation])
{

    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"NewDataStoryboard" bundle:nil];
    newController = [storyboard instantiateInitialViewController];
}
else
{
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"NoNewDataStoryboard" bundle:nil];
    newController = [storyboard instantiateInitialViewController];
}

// Present New View Controller (this example assumes a navigation controller)
[self.navigationController pushViewController:newController animated:YES];
```

If you wanted to instantiate a view controller that isn't the initial view controller in a StoryBoard, you could look to leverage another instance -`(id)instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier` instead of calling `instantiateInitialViewController`

Comment: Tank you very much for your help!